# Is there a way I can install an old Docker version?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've tried the steps from the Docker documentation for an Ubuntu instance, but I get **ERR**:
**E:Version '1.11.0-0-ubuntu-jammy for docker engine was not found**
This is commands i typed:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common

- Add the Docker GPG key:

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

- Add the Docker repository:

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

- Update the package lists:

sudo apt-get update

- Install Docker version 1.11.0:

sudo apt-get install docker-engine=1.11.0-0~ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs)

````
I've also tried another
```none
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys  58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
apt-get update
apt-cache madison docker-engine
````

but I keep getting Err

I've tried several commands but it ends up not fully working. I want to downgrade Docker and install an old version because the newer one doesn't support Docker swarm strategies (such as binpack and random), it only supports Spread as Beta version.

Comment: What error do you get? Please [edit] to include the error messages.

Comment: Why do you want to install a version of docker from 2016? And why do you expect that release of docker would have binaries built for a version of Ubuntu that wouldn't exist until 2022?

Comment: i'm about to try to work with docker swarm classic because the newer one doesn't have the binpack and random strategies and only have spread for now! so am checking if there is a way to go backwards or there isn't

Answer (score 1):

Just install the older version as binaries. Follow the instructions here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/